# Uplay is stuck while trying to update

Tags: wine, playonlinux

I installed Assassin's Creed II using Playonlinux via Wine. The install process completed, and I thought everything was OK, but it wasn't. If I try to start the game, Uplay starts and tries to update but already 3 hours have passed and nothing has changed, the program is still updating. Please try to help me because I'm very tired of using Windows, and want to use Ubuntu all the time.

Answer (score 1):

had the same problem with anno2070.
read the comments below this ticket:
http://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=33673

for me the installation of crypt32.dll with winetricks did the trick :)

but read till end first, cause this will break your updates through uplay.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Thanks!

Comment: 1) Install winetricks (apt-get install winetricks) 2) winetricks crypt32

Comment: How come questions like this get massive amounts of views, yet mine, which are a bit more critical than a game not working..